# PDF generation with report lab issue

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab

I am using reportlab package for PDF generation in my webapp.

I have defined the story and appended the flowables accordingly.

At end, I was endup with an below issue.

[ERROR] [2016-09-09 18:12:20,540] [documents.py|257]: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/sites/dev_mymebook/mymebook/mymebook/../mymebook/mebook/pdf_classes/documents.py", line 252, in render_mebook
    _render_mebook(mebook_info, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/sites/dev_mymebook/mymebook/mymebook/../mymebook/mebook/pdf_classes/documents.py", line 1064, in _render_mebook
    doc.build(story)File "/var/www/sites/dev_mymebook/mymebook/mymebook/../mymebook/mebook/pdf_classes/documents.py", line 195, in build
    self.handle_flowable(flowables)
  File "/var/www/sites/dev_mymebook/live_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py", line 743, in handle_flowable
    self.handle_keepWithNext(flowables)
  File "/var/www/sites/dev_mymebook/live_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py", line 710, in handle_keepWithNext
while i

TypeError: unbound method getKeepWithNext() must be called with Spacer instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

I am unsure where I am missing...?

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Showing some code would be greatly appreciated, probably you are combining some flowables that don't mix.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Issue has resolved, I figure out the problem.